# How to speed up your movement in counter strike?

Tags: counter-strike

I watched other players with some good skills: They move and shoot and their movement is so quick, that I can't aim on them. Can someone please confirm as to how I can move equally as fast?

Comment: A loooot of practice. If you really want to become a pro, it's not only practicing untill you can do the things pro's do, but also understand the tactics of the game behind it. It's not just shooting. You may achieve the same level pro's are, when you practice around 5-10 hours a day, every day. But if you are asking yourself whenever you have to move or not when you are shooting, then.. well.. you might wanna pursue other dreams.....

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Cvars with `sv_` typically are server-side and thus out of your control as a player

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9qXbgrx9rg#t=81s

Comment: Practise makes Perfect. Being good at something is time-consuming. Think to yourself if this is what you'd like to spend your time concentrating on - or whether other ambitions can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to move faster that other players in Counter Strike. The easiest is to use "fast" weapons such as `Steyr Scout`, with it you will run with speed of 260 units/second.

The second fastest weapon(s) is(are) knife, pistols(all of them) and SMGs(all of them except for `P90`), with them you run 250 units/second. After that it's `P90`: 245 units/second.

The slowest weapon is `AWP`, you will only run at 210 units/second, second slowest is `M249`: 220 units/second.

The other option to move faster is to move sideways(not completely strafing, just a bit askew). I don't remember how to do it exactly, but if I remember correctly it was like that: go forward + strafe left/right + move mouse to the left/right. With knife it's possible to get a speed of 274 units/second.

Or, as SaadBen said, you can try learning how to `BunnyHop`, there are gazillion lessons in the web. With `BunnyHop` you will go fastest, but it's extremely difficult to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

A movement technique called ***bunny hopping*** will enable you to move with a lot more agility and make you a lot harder to kill in game. If done correctly it can be used to maintain an above normal speed while holding a knife. I suggest learning to bunnyhop down a slope first. It provides a massive speed boost and makes you impossible to shoot down :)

Also, some players use ***scroll ducking*** which can be done by entering 
**"bind mwheeldown +duck"** 
or 
**"bind mwheelup +duck"** in the game console(~). On flicking the scroll button you will jerk up and down and almost move at maxspeed while maintaining an irregular motion and also making less footstep noise.
This technique is commonly banned at competitive levels.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember in CS 1.6, you might want to learn how to bunny hop and understanding how weapon weight affects your movement speed (knife is the "fastest").

Comment: no, scout is the "fastest"

Comment: Yup, that's true. There's a 200gr difference, but carrying a scout is an endgame change, not something you can do all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Scout is 10% faster than knife/pistol (which are the same, all pistol and knife are 250 u/s, scout is 10% faster than that)

Answer (score -5):

just use bunny hop and type those cheat :-

sv_aira + tap 99999999999
sv_spe + tap 999999999999
sv_maxs + tap 9999999999
sv_airm + tap 99999999999
cl_sid + tap 9999
cl_ups + tap 9999
cl_for + tap 9999
cl_backs + tap 9999
cl_yaw + tap 9999
fps + tap 151
dev + tap 1

you will move very very fast with bunny hop just learn it. sorry for my english

just like that :-